# Android: Learning about Arrays. Need a little help

Tags: android, arrays

So I'm close with my code.  I've been trying to get my Soundboard to utilize Set As Ringtone for two days now. It's obvious I need to utilize Arrays.

Three sections of code, but not quite sure how to implement it.

## 1:  The array decleration:

```
int [] buttonArray = {R.id.button1, R.raw.button2};
```

## 2: The for statement (WRONG - This is what I'm not sure about)

```
for (int i=0; i<buttonArray.length; i++){  
      buttonArray[i];  
      }
```

## 3: The button switch:(WRONG - I know this is wrong too)

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case buttonArray[i]:
```

---

@Ted - Ok, below is my full code.  The Soundboard portion works great, it's the Set as Ringtone that's not working.  And I know why.  I am using R.raw.ifightsong for the function.  I figured I need an array there so it differentiate between the sounds.  Not to mention I am going to have 10 buttons and so I"m going to have A LOT of code.  I wanted to eliminate A LOT of code by using an array.

```
package com.hawkaddictsoundboard;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HawkeyeAddictSoundboardActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button fightsong;
    Button oniowa;

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    int[] soundArray = {R.raw.ifightsong,R.raw.oniowa}; // etc...


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        fightsong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fightsong_button);
        fightsong.setOnClickListener(this);
        oniowa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oniowa_button);
        oniowa.setOnClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(fightsong);  
        registerForContextMenu(oniowa); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fightsong_button:
               if (mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mMediaPlayer.stop();
                   mMediaPlayer.reset();
                   mMediaPlayer.start();

                    }
               else{
                    if (mMediaPlayer!=null){
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ifightsong);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
               break;
        case R.id.oniowa_button:
               if (mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mMediaPlayer.stop();
                   mMediaPlayer.reset();
                   mMediaPlayer.start();

               }
               else{
                    if (mMediaPlayer!=null){
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.oniowa);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
               break;
    }}
     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Set As...");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
     }

     @Override  
     public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
         if(item.getTitle().equals("Ringtone")){function1(item.getItemId());}  
         else if(item.getTitle().equals("Notification")){function2(item.getItemId());}
         else return false; 
     return true;  
     }  

     public void function1(int id){ 
         if (saveringifightsong(R.raw.ifightsong)){  
             // Code if successful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }  
             else  
             {  
             // Code if unsuccessful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

     }

     public void function2(int id){  
         if (savenotifightsong(R.raw.ifightsong)){  
             // Code if successful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }  
             else  
             {  
             // Code if unsuccessful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }}



     public boolean saveringifightsong(int ressound){
         byte[] buffer=null;
         InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
         int size=0;
           try {  
                size = fIn.available();  
                buffer = new byte[size];  
                fIn.read(buffer);  
                fIn.close();  
               } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                return false;  
               }
                String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
                String filename="ifightsong_ring"+".ogg"; 

           boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
           if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

           FileOutputStream save;  
           try {  
            save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
            save.write(buffer);  
            save.flush();  
            save.close();  
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           }      

           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

           File k = new File(path, filename);  

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Iowa Fight Song");  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Hawkeye Sounds ");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

           //Insert it into the database  
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    HawkeyeAddictSoundboardActivity.this,
              RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
              newUri
            );
            return true;  
          }   
     public boolean savenotifightsong(int ressound){
         byte[] buffer=null;
         InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
         int size=0;
           try {  
                size = fIn.available();  
                buffer = new byte[size];  
                fIn.read(buffer);  
                fIn.close();  
               } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                return false;  
               }
                String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
                String filename="ifightsong_not"+".ogg"; 

           boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
           if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

           FileOutputStream save;  
           try {  
            save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
            save.write(buffer);  
            save.flush();  
            save.close();  
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           }      

           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

           File k = new File(path, filename);  

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Iowa Fight Song");  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Hawkeye Sounds ");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

           //Insert it into the database  
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    HawkeyeAddictSoundboardActivity.this,
              RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
              newUri
            );
            return true;  
          }
     public boolean saveringoniowa(int ressound){
         byte[] buffer=null;
         InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
         int size=0;
           try {  
                size = fIn.available();  
                buffer = new byte[size];  
                fIn.read(buffer);  
                fIn.close();  
               } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                return false;  
               }
                String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
                String filename="oniowa_ring"+".ogg"; 

           boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
           if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

           FileOutputStream save;  
           try {  
            save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
            save.write(buffer);  
            save.flush();  
            save.close();  
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           }      

           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

           File k = new File(path, filename);  

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "On Iowa");  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Hawkeye Sounds ");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

           //Insert it into the database  
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    HawkeyeAddictSoundboardActivity.this,
              RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
              newUri
            );
            return true;  
          }
     public boolean savenotoniowa(int ressound){
         byte[] buffer=null;
         InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
         int size=0;
           try {  
                size = fIn.available();  
                buffer = new byte[size];  
                fIn.read(buffer);  
                fIn.close();  
               } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                return false;  
               }
                String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
                String filename="oniowa_not"+".ogg"; 

           boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
           if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

           FileOutputStream save;  
           try {  
            save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
            save.write(buffer);  
            save.flush();  
            save.close();  
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
           }      

           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

           File k = new File(path, filename);  

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "On Iowa");  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Hawkeye Sounds ");  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

           //Insert it into the database  
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    HawkeyeAddictSoundboardActivity.this,
              RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
              newUri
            );
            return true;  
          }

}
```

**EDIT**
Please have a look at my getTag for contextmenu below.  The question is, am I close Ted?

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                    int tag;
                    try {
                        tag = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // null or invalid tag -- how'd that happen?
                        return;
                    }
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Set As...");
     menu.add(0, soundArray[tag], 0, "Ringtone");
     menu.add(0, soundArray[tag], 0, "Notification");
     }

     @Override  
     public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
         if(item.getTitle().equals("Ringtone")){function1(item.getItemId());}  
         else if(item.getTitle().equals("Notification")){function2(item.getItemId());}
         else return false; 
     return true;  
     }  


     public void function1(int tag){ 
             if (savering(soundArray[tag])){  
             // Code if successful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }  
             else  
             {  
             // Code if unsuccessful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

     }
     public void function2(int tag){  

         if (savenot(soundArray[tag])){  
             // Code if successful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }  
             else  
             {  
             // Code if unsuccessful  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes no sense. This statement:

```
int [] = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2};
```

isn't legal Java—no variable name.

The body of your `for` loop isn't a statement (it doesn't *do* anything), so that's not legal either.

The `case` values need to be *compile time* constants. You cannot use a `case` to select among different run-time values. You'll have to re-do the `switch` as something like this:

```
int id = v.getId();
for (int button : buttonArray) {
    if (id == button) {
        // got a hit -- process it
        break; // then end the for loop
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. When I do this kind of thing, I find it useful to use the `android:tag` attribute; it's much more convenient than what you're trying to do. You can set the tag in the layout or do it in code. Here's a method that does it in code.

```
int[] soundArray = { /* ... */ };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    fightsong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fightsong_button);
    fightsong.setOnClickListener(this);
    fightSong.setTag("0");
    oniowa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oniowa_button);
    oniowa.setOnClickListener(this);
    oniowa.setTag("1");
    registerForContextMenu(fightsong);  
    registerForContextMenu(oniowa); 
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int tag;
    try {
        tag = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // null or invalid tag -- how'd that happen?
        return;
    }
    // clear out old media player (if any)
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
    // fire up a media player with the correct sound
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundArray[tag]);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

You can also use the tag instead of the view id when creating the context menu.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to say int[] buttonArray =

Comment: Please look at my edits Ted.  It should make more sense now.  Where do you actually identify buttonArray[0] and [1] though?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain more about what you're trying to accomplish. Also, why is it "obvious" that you need to use arrays?

Comment: @Ted - Ok, I've added all of my code.  If you have better suggestions than an array, I'm all ears.

Comment: @tjberte - I've appended to my answer.

Comment: Wow Ted, I am so close I can almost taste it.  I have the first section exactly right.  The context menu is where I'm stuck now. getTag doesn't exactly work like getId.

Comment: @tjberte - `getTag` returns whatever tag you set, which I was proposing be an index into your array(s). You just need to use `Integer.parseInt(view.getTag())`. You should probably wrap that in a try-catch block in case you are unexpectedly executing that code for a view that isn't one of your buttons with a tag. I see where you're passing the id to `function1` or `function2`, but I don't see it being used there. So I can't offer anything more specific.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for how much you've helped me Ted.  Arrays are a whole new ball game for me and I'm almost there.  Please look at my original post again.  I've added the context menu section with what I think is right?  I just don't know how to pass the soundArray[tag] down to the function.

Comment: Just use `tag` instead of `soundArray[tag]` inside `function1` and `function2`. You've already looked up the `soundArray` entry when you created each menu item.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  Finally got it all working!  Now for some reason my apk crashes when trying to install it on my phone.  Another problem for to ask about though.

Answer (score 0):

A sample solution for the issue is below
Regarding your code block in swicth case

```
you are repeating the information regarding mMediaPlayer in each case which is increasing your code. 

switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fightsong_button:
               if (mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mMediaPlayer.stop();
                   mMediaPlayer.reset();
                   mMediaPlayer.start();

                    }
               else{
                    if (mMediaPlayer!=null){
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ifightsong);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
               break;
        case R.id.oniowa_button:
               if (mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mMediaPlayer.stop();
                   mMediaPlayer.reset();
                   mMediaPlayer.start();

               }
               else{
                    if (mMediaPlayer!=null){
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.oniowa);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
               break;
    }}
```

Moreover to reduce the line of codes instead of swith case you can use if else to achive the same functionality with less code.

Comment: I don't see any changes that you made?  This section looks identical to mine.

Comment: 1.to reduce the line of codes instead of swith case you can use if else to achive the same  2. you are repeating the information regarding mMediaPlayer in each case which is increasing your code. 
hope this helps

Comment: Ok, that addresses on problem, but my biggest problem is trying to get the bottom section working(the ringtones).  I need an array so that when I click a button, it corresponds to the right sound and then assigns it the right ringtone.  In the above code right now, it will only assign R.raw.ifightsong as the ringtone or notification. I need an array to connection function 1 and 2 to the different sounds.

Comment: hmm... If I' m getting it correct use array  int []arr = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.2}; Then instead of switch case use your array with if else ... for(i=0;i<arr.length; i++)if(arr[i]==v.get(Id)){do this}break; ..

Comment: You're not looking at all of my code.  There a couple of different arrays that I would need.  For the button and for the raw(s).  But like I said, look at the ringtone settings further down.  That's where I need the help.